# Не удается применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "OleDbDataAdapter"

Tags: c#, oledb

Не знаю как возвращать значение в dataAdapter. Помогите пожалуйста, на C# неделю назад начал программировать. Заранее спасибо)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;

namespace aqua{

class qwer
{


    OleDbConnection connection;//по строке подключения создать подключение между проектом и бд
    OleDbCommand command;// операция вставки, удоления редактированиия данных
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter;// для получения набора данных из базы
    DataTable bufferTable;

    public qwer(string Conn)
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection(Conn);
        bufferTable = new DataTable();
    }

    public DataTable UpdatePerson()
    {
        connection.Open();
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM категория", connection);
        bufferTable.Clear();
        dataAdapter.Fill(bufferTable);
        connection.Close();
        return bufferTable;
    }

    public void Add(string textBox1, string textBox2, string textBox3)
    {
        connection.Open();
        command = new OleDbCommand($"INSERT INTO категория([название рыбы], категория,[описание категории]) VALUES([@название рыбы], @категория, [@описание категории])", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("название рыбы", textBox1);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("категория", textBox2);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("описание категории",  textBox3);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }

    public String SelectCategory(String codeCategory)
    {
        connection.Open();
        string cmdStr = "SELECT[категория] FROM категория WHERE[Код категории] = " + codeCategory;
        dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdStr, connection);
        return dataAdapter["категория"];
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить от метода SelectCategory?

Comment: id строки в столбце категории из столбца код категории

Comment: Вы ООП знаете? Если да, то я сделаю ответ с ООП, если нет - без него.

Comment: к сожалению нет